# Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, faster-than-light, observers

Does special relativity require faster than light information transfer to verify length contraction and time dilation?

How does the "outside observer" measure these variables? I guess the outside observer cannot exist within the universe and is "outside" the universe somehow observing. Also would the outside observer somehow need to have the objective definition of a meter and a second?

Also isn't the only way to record length and time, by light?

If you could refer me to experimental techniques and evidence that would be great!! Theory is everywhere but what would we be without the experimentalist!

Comment: We calculate the time dilation and then we verify it, as in the muon experiment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon I suggest you look up wikipedia for length contraction experiments

Comment: Like in the muon experiment, we're usually forced to appreciate the measurement as a black box. I really want to know HOW they do these insane experiments

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2e9ltbbOwtc   Hope this is worth it, have not got time to look at it.  And a paper http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1963AmJPh..31..342F

Comment: "Also isn't the only way to record length and time, by light?" -  More precisely, the only way to record distance is by time it takes light to pass it. And yes, it is exactly how the current standard of length is defined: 1 meter is 1/299,792,458 part of light-second. Recording time is a separate matter addressed by the atomic clock.

Comment: Why do you think it takes faster than light travel to measure length contraction and time dilation?

Comment: Where is the observer? If is at any distance away from the event or particle moving, light (photons) communicates information from some point to another and that occurs at the speed of light. I have no idea what was taken into consideration when making these verifications so forgive me.

Comment: In the light of your "faster than light" remark regarding measurements, are you maybe confusing "observer" with a human-being/recording-instrument located at one specific place? An observer is really to be thought of as a network of rods and clocks, and _ideally_ recording an event happens entirely locally and therefore instantaneously. Relaying this information to some other part of the universe indeed takes finite time (and therefore cannot be instantaneous), but relativity per se does not deal with this explicitly. See "Spacetime Physics" by Taylor and Wheeler.

Comment: Yes I am confused with observer, it's quite ambiguous even though it's so important

Answer (score 1):

Analysing the constant speed of light for Special Relativity starts as thought experiments.   The thinker knows when and where things actually happen, and then works out what observers must see, and when, so that the speed of light is always constant.

From that you get time dilation, the Lorentz contraction, and the relativity of simultaneity.

These three then tell the thinker what else must be true about where and when things happen, and how the when must depend on the movement of the observer.  When has to be different for different observers.

Experimenters checking the theory have to correct the 'when' they see for the time it takes for them to see it, to get the theoretical answers.

It all checks out.